# How to jump to the specific initial tab route dynamically route name?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have problem jump to the specific tab navigation base on my dynamic initial route name.

Here is the scenario:

1. If the user just want to login, The initial route of Auth tab navigation must be on **ProductBrowsing**
2. If the user first time in the application and user register in the app, The initial route of Auth tab navigation must be on **AddProduct**.

Problem: When I login the screen not changing the screen stuck on login the navigation replace is not working.

Handler Login:

```
   const HandlerLoginBtn = async () => {
    const user_data = {
      mobile_number: username,
      password: password
    }
    await dispatch(LoginAuthentication(user_data)).then((res) => {
      if(res?.payload?.message == 'Login Success') {
        
        if(redirection == 'ProductBrowsing') {
          navigation.replace('ProductBrowsing')
        }
        else if(redirection == 'AddProduct') {
          navigation.replace('AddProduct')
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

Auth Tab:

```
   function AuthenticateTabNav() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator  tabBarOptions={{
            inactiveTintColor: '#032363',
            labelStyle: { fontSize:12, fontWeight:'500'},
            style: {
              backgroundColor: '#ffff',
            }
        }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'BUY',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused , color, size }) => (
                        focused ? (
                            <Image h="4" w="4" 
                            source={require('./assets/tab_icons/buy/blue_buy.png')}></Image>
                        ): (
                            <Image h="4" w="4" 
                            source={require('./assets/tab_icons/buy/black_buy.png')}></Image>
                        )
                        
                    ),
                }}
                name="ProductBrowsing"
                component={ProductBrowsingScreen}
            />

            <Tab.Screen
                options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'SELL',
                    tabBarIcon: ({ focused , color, size }) => (
                        focused ? (
                            <Image h="4" w="4" 
                            source={require('./assets/tab_icons/sell/blue_sell.png')}></Image>
                        ): (
                            <Image h="4" w="4" 
                            source={require('./assets/tab_icons/sell/black_sell.png')}></Image>
                        )
                    ),
                }}
                name="AddProduct"
                component={AddProductScreen}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Navigation:

```
    const AuthenticatedNav = () => {
    
    const {redirection} = useSelector((state) => state.user)
    const [firstScreen, setFirstScreen] = useState('');
    console.log(firstScreen)

    useEffect(() => {
        setFirstScreen(redirection)
    }, [])
    

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={firstScreen == '' ? 'ProductBrowsing' : 'AddProduct'} headerMode='none'>
            <Stack.Screen component={AuthenticateTabNav}  name={firstScreen == '' ? 'ProductBrowsing' : 'AddProduct' } />  
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Redux State:

```
builder.addCase(LoginAuthentication.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
 
  if(action.payload?.message == 'Invalid Username Or Password') {
    state.auth_access = []
    state.isLoggedIn = false
    state.isLoading = false
    state.redirection = ''
  }else {
    state.auth_access = action.payload
    state.isLoggedIn = true
    state.redirection = 'ProductBrowsing'
  }
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a full sample here https://snack.expo.dev/O3vW24UCl

If I understand correctly, you want to navigate from one tab to another depending on the user login state.

Changing the `initialRouteName` on the main Stack is not useful as you are moving within the tabs in your case.
What you want to do is the same but on the `Tab.Navigator`.

```
const Tabs = () => {
  const isUserLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => {
    return state.isUserLoggedIn;
  });

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName={isUserLoggedIn ? "AddProduct" : "ProductBrowsing"}
      >
      <Tab.Screen
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'BUY',
        }}
        name="ProductBrowsing"
        component={ProductBrowsingScreen}
      />

      <Tab.Screen
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'SELL',
        }}
        name="AddProduct"
        component={AddProductScreen}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Obviously, in the sample the state is not persisted.

Answer (score 0):

few days back i just came across this functionality
and my methodology works fine for me ..
So,i'm sure it works in general..

i use the useContext hook to update the initialRouteName dynamically.

```
import {createContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
export const InitialRouteContext = createContext({
initialRoute: '',
updateInitialRoute: () => {},});
```

Making the context as you do and wrapping the app (entry point) with InitialRouteProvider (just do..)

use AsyncStorage to store initialRouteName in a device, so wherever you initialRoute, update the storage and call initialRouteName from context too.

```
const initialRouteCtx = useContext(InitialRouteContext);
  const setInitialRoute = initialRouteCtx.initialRoute
? initialRouteCtx.initialRoute
: `default_screen`;
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={setInitialRoute} screenOptions={{...}}>
```